Why does the output of a stable LTI system approach the input mathematically speaking?
If an LTI system is modelled using the equation:$$a_n\frac{d^{n} y(t)}{dt^{n}}+
                        \cdots +a_{1}\frac{d y(t)}{dt}+a_{0}y(t)=b_m
                        \frac{d^{m} x(t)}{dt^{m}}+\cdots 
                        +b_{1}\frac{d x(t)}{dt}+b_{0}x(t)$$ and if the characteristic equation $a_ns^n+\cdots +a_{1}s+a_{0}$ has $n$ distinct roots, then the zero-input response of the system can be written as: $$y(t)=c_1e^{p_1t}+c_2e^{p_2t}+\cdots+c_ne^{p_nt}$$ where $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_n$ are the poles of the transfer function of the system. If the system is stable, meaning the poles are all complex numbers with negative real parts, the output obviously approaches the input, zero, as $t\to \infty$. $$\\$$ But why does the output $y(t)$ eventually approach the input $x(t)$ even when $x(t)\neq0$?. How does that relate to the impulse response of the system $h(t)$, where $y(t)=x(t)\ast h(t)$?

Think of of the Laplace Transform applied to the ode with null initial conditions and $n \ge m$.
$$
G_a(s)\hat y = G_b(s)\hat x\Rightarrow \hat y = \frac{G_b(s)}{G_a(s)}\hat x
$$
Now if the zeros of $G_a(s)=0$ are distinct and have negative real parts,the expansion of $\frac{G_b(s)}{G_a(s)}$ gives
$$
\frac{G_b(s)}{G_a(s)}= c_0+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{s+p_j}
$$
If $n=m$ then $c_0\ne 0$ and all the terms $\frac{c_j}{s+p_j}$ give antitransforming, exponential decaying factors, or
$$
y(t) = c_0\delta(t)\circledast x(t) + \sum_{j=1}^n c_je^{-p_j t}\circledast x(t),\ \ \ \ n = m
$$
and
$$
y(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_je^{-p_j t}\circledast x(t),\ \ \ \ n > m
$$
Concluding, if $n > m$, y(t) follows $x(t)$ attenuated and decaying by at last, the exponential generated by the nearest zero of $G_a(s)=0$ to the imaginary axes. If $n=m$, the input $x(t)$ also propagates directly to the output $y(t)$ scaled by $c_0$.

Assuming that the input $x$ is very slowly moving relative to the real parts of the eigenvalues (and their implied decay rates or half-life), then the excitation of the left side from time step to infinitesimally distant time step is so small, that the correction to the next "equilibrium" is almost instantaneous. In the end, $y$ moves as slowly, adiabatically, as $x$ (one could also compare Fourier or Laplace transforms for the dominant frequency content).
Which means that the values of the higher derivative get rapidly smaller with each order. In the end it remains
$$
a_0y(t)\simeq b_0x(t).
$$
One can also take the first derivative on both sides into consideration and treat the sum as linear Taylor polynomial to get the slightly more exact
$$
a_0y\left(t+\frac{a_1}{a_0}\right)\simeq b_0x\left(t+\frac{b_1}{b_0}\right)
$$
